# How to publish entire remix workspace to my github repo?

Tags: remix

I would like to save an entire workspace in a github repo.
Or create/load/populate a workspace from a github repo.
I can load and save individual files as gists but I'm interested in publishing the entire directory structure, not just individal files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Download` the workspace onto a local desktop and push the content to your GitHub. To load a workspace from Github, you can use `Clone`.

[image]

See: https://medium.com/remix-ide/securing-you-file-in-remix-how-to-clone-and-push-f1350111aa13

Comment: Its worth noting that the key is to use the dgit plugin.  Also not sure about the wording "download the workspace onto a local desktop".